# How to check for a module exits and include it in resources in grails

Tags: grails, grails-resources-plugin

I have a module defined as below, which depends on other module.

```
'myTestService' {
    dependsOn "otherTestService"
}
```

**otherTestService** is defined in another plugin But that plugin may not be included always,So the app works fine if the module found otherwise, it will throw an error.

So, How to safely include this module.

Comment: Where is this configuration being made? Give a bit more context in your question. (It almost looks like something in `Resources.groovy`)

Comment: it is in one of my custom resources file like testsResources.groovy